# Alternate Way To Write Razor Code/ Can HTML Work Instead?

Tags: c#, razor-pages

Is there anyway to rewrite razor code in html format to get the same results?

I honestly did not try anything but google a few solution but could not get help

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h3> Create new Genre</h3>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" /> 
    @Html.Partial("_BackToListPartial")
</div>
```

IS there a pure html version of this code that will produce the same result without using lambda expression?

No errors, just asking for alternate ways

Comment: Are you asking for the `<form>` tag?

Comment: Does it work now? The answer likely won't be simple because of the validation. It's going to generate some JavaScript. The literal answer would be to look in the browser and see what HTML and JavaScript it generates. You could use that instead of Razor. But when you look at it you'll likely see that it's a lot longer and more complicated than the code you've shown above, which is why we have Razor to help us generate it.

Comment: I am talking about the lambada functions that were used, is there a way to rewrite in pure html?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET Core then you can use [Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which look like standard HTML.

For example, `@using (Html.BeginForm())` could instead use the form tag helper:

```
<form asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction" method="post">

</form>
```

Comment: I am talking about the lambada functions that were used, is there a way to rewrite in pure html? `<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h3> Create new Genre</h3>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>`

Comment: @Randy if there's no suitable tag helper to achieve what you want, it's possible to create your own tag helpers.

Comment: for example i was able to rewrite this sytnax "@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })  " into this format and it works "<label for="Name"class = "control-label col-md-2">Name</label>"